# Create a JSON with HashMap with key object and value is an other HashMap <Object,Object>

Tags: java, json, hashmap

Hy guys I have this HashMap:

```
HashMap<User, HashMap<ArrayList<User>, Yield>> userYield = new HashMap<>();
```

User and Yelda are objects and, after I fill the HashMap, I've to put the HashMap in a JSON, how I could be?

Edit:
with `JSONObject` this is the result :

```
{
" id:4575, nome:Bill, cognome:Man": {
    "[ id:3743, nome:John, cognome:Redo,  id:3243, nome:Gian, cognome:Vand,  id:34243, nome:Mike, cognome:Mill]": {
        "incassoAzienda": 80,
        "incasso": 125,
        "idRendimento": 1,
        "incassoAgenzia": 45
    }
}
```

}
What I want is something like this, if it is possible:

```
{
" id:4575, nome:Bill, cognome:Man": {
    "{ id:3743, nome:"John", cognome:"Redo",  id:"3243", nome:"Gian", cognome:"Vand",  id:"34243", nome:"Mike", cognome:"Mill"}": {
        "incassoAzienda": 80,
        "incasso": 125,
        "idRendimento": 1,
        "incassoAgenzia": 45
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There are several ways to do this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Note that `HashMap<User, HashMap<ArrayList<User>, Yield>>` would mean json like `{ "gianluca23" : { ["gianluca23"] : {"someYield"}}}`, i.e. you'd want to use a list as the key. I might be missing something but I'm pretty sure that's not valid json. So what should the resulting json look like or at least what do you want it to express (and what would the nested maps express)? (And what did you try so far?)

Comment: @Thomas I edit the post with what I tried and what I want if it is possible

Comment: I also tried with `new Gson().toJson`  but the JSON is not valid

Comment: You can't use objects as keys in json. What you've done so far would be converting the key to a json string and using that string as a key in json. While this can be done this can lead to hard-to-use structures since json doesn't have any ordering requirement so the string might be different even if the data didn't change (attributes can be in different order). Also, why exactly is your nested map's key a list? What exactly does that mean?

Comment: @Thomas thanks, I change the structure of HashMap. Now I have this : `HashMap<String, HashMap< String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, UserYeld>>>>`

Comment: You still didn't describe what you want to express. If we know what you're trying to achieve (what should the maps/json represent in some detail) and what source data you're working with we might be able to suggest a proper structure.

Answer (score 0):

try GSON library from Google

add this to gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

Add the following methods to the User class

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public String toJson(){
    return new Gson().toJson(this);
}
public static User initFromJson(String json){
    return new Gson().fromJson(json, User.class);
}
public static List<User> initFromJsonArray(String json){
    List<User> lst = new ArrayList<>();
    lst.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Gson().fromJson(json, User[].class)));
    return lst;
}
public static String listToJson(List<User> lst){
    return new Gson().toJson(lst.toArray());
}
```